# Office 365 and AD FS middleman in C#

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs2.0, office365

We're using Microsoft SSO kit version 4.5 (liveatedu) currently to SSO to Office 365. We need ADFS in place before end of this year.

**Even though we've installed and tested ADFS + Office 365 in a test environment, its very vanilla. We'd rather users sign in from a customized/branded page hosted in our datacenter instead of the IdpInitiatedSignOn.aspx or the login.onmicrosoft.com redirect.**

Most articles on ADFS setup for Office 365 simply end at verifying if ADFS is working. For instance [this one](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205462.aspx). What if we need to tie an existing FBA+LDAP webapp to ADFS so that once signed in, Office 365 is one of the many places the user can go.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx) looked promising until about half way down it referred to the sign in page residing in cloud, which cannot be branded/customized.

There are several 3rd party companies offering SSO to Office 365 like [centrify](http://www.centrify.com/), [onelogin](http://www.onelogin.com/) and [okta](http://www.okta.com/). Where can I find more help on how they achieved it? Any code sample would be awesome!

Comment: Came across this blogpost by Omar Venado http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omarv/archive/2012/11/15/developing-windows-store-apps-for-sharepoint-online-with-sso-single-sign-on.aspx . Haven't tried but reading it looks this may be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a SAML IdP or a WS-Federation IP-STS. Customize the login pages of that. Then, add a claims provider trust in ADFS to connect it w/ your IdP/IP-STS. Then, add an RP trust to O365 and friends. Your resulting architecture will look something like this (old drawing that I used for something else, so it's not exact):

[image]

> What if we need to tie an existing FBA+LDAP webapp to ADFS so that
>   once signed in, Office 365 is one of the many places the user can go.

Exactly. To do this, your FBA+LDAP webapp must be updated to speak either SAML or WS-Fed. Then, you can connect it to ADFS. (We're doing this exact thing for one of our customers ATM, sans O365. Ping me off the list to discuss details.)

Issues you may run into:

- User must select which claims provider to login w/ at ADFS (home realm disco) because you have more than one. AD trust can't be deleted or disabled.
- SAML that ADFS wants takes a bit of tweaking and debugging to get right.
- If your downstream RP doesn't send a authN context, you will have difficulty inserting it on a per-RP basis before redirecting from ADFS to your IdP. If they do, it will work fine, even if translating between SAML and WS-Fed.
- You now have double the certs. How can you reduce this and share the certs between ADFS and your FBA webapp? (Might not be possible or even desirable, but so many issues are due to certs. So, reducing them to as few as possible should be your goal.)
- If your down-stream RP has a requirement for some sort of data or authentication strength, you can block access in ADFS w/ an authZ rule. Doing this will require your upstream claims provider to put data in the response that ADFS can use to fulfill this requirement.
- Likewise, you can lookup data in ADFS using an attribute store to get additional claims. Helpful if you have access to those databases, but you may not in ADFS.

Anyway, HTH!

Comment: Travis, thanks a lot for the detailed answer. Your suggestion to implement code an IdP and add it to ADFS as trusted claims provider makes sense but it also sounds like a complex job for a single developer like me. I found a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/omarv/archive/2012/11/15/developing-windows-store-apps-for-sharepoint-online-with-sso-single-sign-on.aspx) which has code that sends and receives SAML. Only thing I'm stuck at this point is that the code works for SharePoint but not for Outlook OWA. I need the auth cookie URL (STS) for OWA and the names of cookies OWA service expects

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by trying a totally different approach. I don't need to do this programmatically, at least not in my case. I followed [this](http://www.vankeyenberg.be/?p=1281) article basically to configure my "middleman" MVC4 portal as an ADFS **relying party**. ADFS was already installed in my case which is a large chunk of that article - so I started from "Application side configuration" portion.

Main thing that helped is the **Identity and Access tool for VS** ([msdn](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e21bf653-dfe1-4d81-b3d3-795cb104066e))

One thing vankeyenberg's article did not mention was configuring the claims on the ADFS server. Without this I was getting "username null" error when enumerating claims in my MVC4 app especially where I had `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. This is how I solved that: After adding your MVC4 application to ADFS as relying party trust using WIF Federation Utility `("C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Identity Foundation SDK\v4.0\FedUtil.exe")`,

1. Modify global.asax.cs in relying party (MCV4) to use NameIdentifier claims type in Application_Start as `AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;`
2. Configure MVC4 app's FederationMetadata.xml to request more claims in the `<fed:ClaimTypesRequested>` section

   `<auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />
   <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />
   <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />
   <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" Optional="true" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706" />`
3. Uncomment  additional claims in the `<applicationService><claimTypeRequired>` section of the MVC4 app's web.config
4. **Configure ADFS server to send claims requested by MVC4 app**

   1. Right click your relying party trust and click Edit Claim Rules
   2. Click Add Rules
   3. Select Send LDAP attributes as claims from dropdown
   4. Give the rule any name, and select Active Directory as attribute store
   5. Add some mappings like UPN, Email address, samaccountname